# Design proportions behind bootstrap4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I would very appreciate if you could explain or point me to some resource where the logic behind design proprotions is explained in bootstrap for there topics:

- Columns

 - Rem and how its defined

 - Rem paddings/margins

Answer (score 0):

> For design proportions,columns etc... you can check Bootstrap's [Grid System](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)
>
> Check out how `Rem` is defined [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/) where you can additionally read about the difference between `Rem` and `Em`.